# Calling more than 1 SET! LOOP, imacros

Tags: imacros

hello I use this code to fill from CSV , imacros in firefox .

Hello , I'm using this code in imacros to draw 1 line of CSV and fill 1 website form.

```
VERSION BUILD=8530828 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE C:\22853.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=http://www.publianuncia.com/site/crearAnuncioMundoanuncio/22853
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:titulo-22853
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:titulo-22853-inplaceeditor ATTR=NAME:value CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:titulo-22853-inplaceeditor ATTR=*
```

I call the first line of the CSV , to fill a web form.
what I want now and I can not do this, you call more than 1 line of CSV , to fill a web form.
I have 6 lines in the CSV and want to call 6 to fill only 1 web form.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to play this macro in loop mode?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply code or Play (LOOP) with MAX: 6